# linking answers: suppose several questions have essentially the same answer?

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to link an answer from question 1, say, to question 2 if answer 1 works or enhances all or part of question 2?  I see many questions that have essentially the same answer.

Comment: Just link the answer in the comments and it will appear in the "Linked section". For example, I'll post a link, say, :    http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/reevaluating-the-book-policy . Ok, now it will appear in the                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Linked" Section  . .  . ...

Comment: Thanks, this is fine.  I see so many questions that are essentially but not exactly the same.  It might help both posers and viewers to see the many different ways of saying the same thing.  Are there magnetic monopoles vs why aren't Maxwell's eqns symmetric?  Does the photon have mass vs does the photon decay?  Etc.

Comment: Then you could write "Related:...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. But if you find that an existing answer to one question also applies to another question:

1. Check and see if the questions are duplicates, and if so, flag one as a duplicate of the other
2. Otherwise, you can quote the relevant parts of an answer (whether yours or someone else's) and include a link to it in your answer, just as you would quote the relevant parts of, and link to, an external website. (Of course make sure your answer is self-contained so that people don't *have* to click on the link to get the point.)

Comment: Added: if the questions really are *exactly* duplicates of one another than there is a question merge feature available to the diamond mods.

Comment: I don't consider exact duplicates in my question. They are easy to deal with. And quoting a longish answer is inefficient. I wouldn't do that in a paper or on a website.  I would make my point with or without a quote and then give a reference.  So the answer to my question is apparently: no, which is too bad.

Comment: @John Well, essentially, that is true. There is no way to "automatically" link an answer between multiple questions.